# How do I target all h2 tags except those within a certain container

Tags: html, css

I have an article that contains a gallery, but I do not want the styling for the article's h2 tags to affect h2's inside the gallery. I have tried using the :not() pseudo class, but it seems I can't use this for this problem.

I want to know if it's possible without overriding the article h2 styling. (In this case it h2 but it actually concerns a lot of tags and a lot of css).

**Example**

HTML:

```
<h2>This is a default h2</h2>
<div class="article">
  <h2>This should use article h2 styling</h2>
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <div class="gallery">
    <h2>This should use default styling</h2>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  </div>
  <p>Paragraph 3</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: green;
}
.article h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: blue;
}
.gallery {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/sorenhusted/b774p8be/3/

Comment: Are all the `h2` that need to be styled directly under `.article`? If yes, use the child selector `>`.

Comment: No not always. This is the issue. I have also put this in a comment to the answer by @Paulie_D

Comment: I just replied to your comment under Paulie's answer also. If it is not always a direct child then [this](https://jsfiddle.net/p1x2rmdL/) is your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need the direct child selector `>`.

Per [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)

> The `>` combinator separates two selectors and matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are direct children of elements matched by the first. By contrast, when two selectors are combined with the descendant selector, the combined selector expression matches those elements matched by the second selector for which there exists an ancestor element matched by the first selector, regardless of the number of "hops" up the DOM.

```
.article > h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: blue;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/b774p8be/5/)

Comment: Ah, this seems like the most straightforward solution.

Comment: @user3010932 What exactly are the *weird stuff* that you are referring to? Do you mean the structure of your HTML won't be consistent?

Comment: This is true in most cases, but some times the journalists that writes the articles do weird stuff like:
'<strong><h2>title</h2></strong>' or '<div><h2>title</h2></div>'
So direct child selector will not always work

Comment: @user3010932: In that case, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/p1x2rmdL/) is your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, It's just hard to change how editors work as a simple frontender :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.article>h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: blue;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/b774p8be/4/

Answer (score 1):

Direct child accessor (`>`) is your friend!

In your CSS, just replace `.article h2` with `.article > h2`, and there you go :-)

Basically, it says that "only an `h2` element which is a **direct** child of a `.article` element will be affected.

https://jsfiddle.net/b774p8be/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `.article .gallery h2` to the same style used for default `h2` likeso:

```
h2, .article .gallery h2 {
 font-size: 30px;
 color: green;
}
```